# Decoding of 4k video causing overflow of buffer in a multi process application

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, hevc

I am quite new in working with FFMPEG. Please excuse me if I made any mistake while explaining my problem.

I am working on an application where PCAP captures 1316 bytes of data split that into 188 bytes and writes it into it to corresponding shared memory. The other process reads the data and decode using ffmpeg and process it.

This whole process is working fine with H264 and HEVC video. 
The problem comes with 4k video. While decodig the 4k video I am encountering buffer overflow. 
I have observed that on a machine with high CPU frequence the overflow rate was less. Hence If I can reduce the time taken to decode and process the video data at ffmpeg might solve my problem. I am not able to find a good solution for my problem.

Is there any way to speed up the process at ffmpeg decoder?, is thre any other way to supress the overflows?

Comment: You should of course show your code/`ffmpeg` command and resulting complete console output.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the buffer size. It can be done via -analyzeduration [buffersize] parameter option